# How to set "ShowField" in peoplepicker using powershell

Tags: powershell, people-picker

Does  anyone know how to set "ShowField" in people picker using powershell ?
For ex.x, to set the "Required" property, we can user `$SiteColumn.required="true"` , but for showfield, `$siteColumn.showfield="Name"` , throws error that the property does not exist

Comment: What are you trying to display. is it the complete properties of the user or you want just the name of the user to be displayed

Comment: There are a few site columns of User type (i.e. People Picker). In the visual studio soln, I tried to set the ShowField="Name" for these site columns and also in the Lists Schema. But after adding a new list item, I noticed that the "Show Field" is still set to "Account". I am trying to set the ShowField through powershell to Name for these site columns so that they display the user name.

Comment: Does anybody have an answer to this? I'm stuck here :(

Answer (score 0):

Setting this ShowField can be a bit confusing because the drop down is filled with display values of these columns and not with the internal names that you have to use in your Visual Studio solution.

[Here](https://prasadpathak.wordpress.com/2013/10/10/setting-show-field-for-person-or-group-type-column-using-powershell/) is a good overview of these values. If you look into the column on the right side you can see that "Name" is what the front-end shows as "Account".

If you want to change the ShowField of another type of Lookup column, you can can find these values with your browser as well.
For example with Chrome: right-click on the drop down with the ShowField, "Inspect element" and the values in this drop down are the values that you need in Visual Studio.